# strange behaviour with c# lambda expression using random

Tags: c#, random, lambda

I want to filter a list of double values 
I want number of items in this list that are greater or equal 
than a random value

When I use random function inside the lambda expression the number of items
founds doesn't correspond to the amount expected. When I put random function outside lamda expression, the code is working right
here is not working version vs working version

not working code:

```
List<double> vecteur = new List<double> { 0.45, 0.5, 1 };
List<int> lstcompteurs = new List<int> { 0,0,0};
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {                
     int index = vecteur.FindIndex(a => a > r.NextDouble());
     lstcompteurs[index]++;    
}
foreach (int cpt in lstcompteurs) {
   Console.WriteLine(cpt);
}
Console.Read();
```

output :
448
288
264

we notice that 288 represents much more than 5% of the sample.

working code:

```
List<double> vecteur = new List<double> { 0.45, 0.5, 1 };
List<int> lstcompteurs = new List<int> { 0,0,0};
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   double b = r.NextDouble();
   int index = vecteur.FindIndex(a => a > b);
   lstcompteurs[index]++;    
}
foreach (int cpt in lstcompteurs) {
    Console.WriteLine(cpt);
}
Console.Read();
```

output:
443
48
509

As you see 48 represents indeed 5% of the sample.

I do not understand what is going on with the first version of my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
int index = vecteur.FindIndex(a => a > r.NextDouble());
```

Finding the index will call `r.NextDouble()` again every time LINQ is doing a check (quite a lot times). `a > r.NextDouble()` is nothing else than a ([anonymous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions)) function LINQ is using to check if the index is a match. This means every comparison is done with a new random value. If you find the index like

```
double b = r.NextDouble();
int index = vecteur.FindIndex(a => a > b);
```

you are always using the same value to do the comparision.

Comment: thanks a lot we just found the problem with debugger